# Create a method that fills different classes from the result of an SQL

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server, api

I am working on an API project, I have to generate JSON trees from table information in the company's databases, according to some requests.

I have divided the project, in class by table, that is, each table in the database has created its corresponding class with its constructor and its getters and setters.

Now let's imagine that we have three tables C1, C2 and C3, which all have the data a b, cod.

The classes will contain the properties a and b, and the methods get a / b and set a / b, cod does not have to be in the class.

When I have to ask for a single table and fill in a single class, the method I have chosen works very well, it is to say.

select a, b from c1

fill in class c1 with the result of the previous selection, calling the method of filling in c1 and building the JSON, and even there everything is correct.

The problem comes when several tables are involved in the select, which I don't know how to do to fill in the multiple classes that can reach me in a certain select, for example

```
select c1.a, c2.b, c3.a from c1 inner join c2 on c1.cod = c2.cod left join c3 on c2.cod = c3.cod
```

I do not know how to classify this data that I receive, and send it to each corresponding class, the only thing that had occurred to me was to go through the recordset three times and make three calls corresponding to the methods of filling the class, since each class knows Identify each data obtained from the select, by an alias assigned to it, and check if the alias exists in the result of the sql, which assigns it to the method that corresponds to it.

Any ideas or any changes please, I'm a bit blocked with this

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build your own ORM. Why don't you use something like Entity Framework, which does all the object instantiation and initialization from data for you?

Comment: I'm going to investigate that line, let's see what I get, thanks. I didn't know about the existence of ORM